# How can I print the value of this variable upon pressing the UIButton?

Tags: iphone, uibutton

```
// My Button code
UIButton *ticketButtonObj=[[ticketButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 115.0f, 500.0f, 40.0f) ;
int col=10;

[ticketButtonObj addTarget:self action:@selector(ShowNumber:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.window addSubview:ticketButtonObj];
// ...   
- (void) ShowNumber:(id)sender{
    // here i want to get the Value of Col
}
```

In the above code when I press the button, I want to print the value of col variable in the `ShowNumber` method. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Col is a local variable and is therfore destroyed after the method returns.

you need to create a instance variable for you to be able to access the value.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a normal local variable and I recommend not using an int. Use an `NSInteger` and set it as a property:

```
@interface YourClassName : UIViewController
{
    NSInteger col;
}
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger col;
```

Then `@synthesize` the variable `col` and use it anywhere you like in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
UIButton *ticketButtonObj=[[ticketButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 115.0f, 500.0f, 40.0f) ;
int col=10;
ticketButtonObj.tag = col;
[ticketButtonObj addTarget:self action:@selector(ShowNumber:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.window addSubview:ticketButtonObj];

// ... 

- (void) ShowNumber:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"%@", [(UIButton*) sender tag]);}
```